# Como modificar data não preenchida no formulário para o dia atual?

Tags: php, data

Tentei fazer com `isset`, tipo:

```
$var1 = isset($_POST["namedocampo"]) ? $_POST["namedocampo"] : date('d/m/Y');
```

E com `if`, tipo:

```
if ($_POST["namedocampo"] == "") {

$var1 = date('d/m/Y');

}
```

Mas sempre que o campo não é preenchido aparece a data `31/12/1969`.

O campo de entrada da data está assim:

```
<input type="text"  id="iddocampo" name="namedocampo" class="form-control" maxlength="10" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" onkeyup="formatar('##/##/####', this, event)"></label>
```

E o campo de saída está assim:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
<span class="badge"><?php echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($var1)); ?></span>
Data:
</li>
```

Comment: Experimentou olhar no console do Firefox/Chrome pra ver o que o formulário está mandando pro servidor? Você esperaria que esse `keyup` garantisse que o campo em branco mandasse a string vazia pro servidor, mas é de fato isso que está acontecendo?

Comment: Esse `keyup` é pra chamar uma função em js pra formatar a data e validar o campo pra abrir um botão. A resposta abaixo funcionou... Valeu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro verifique se o **method** do seu form está como **POST**

Segue abaixo exemplo:

```
<form action="arquivo.php" method="post">
    Data: <input type="text" name="data"/>
</form>
```

**arquivo.php**

```
<?php
    $data = empty($_POST["data"]) ? date("d/m/Y") : $_POST["data"];
    echo $data;
```

Para o strtotime funcionar a data precisa estar em um dos padrões descritos em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php

> Para sua saída experimente o código abaixo

```
date("d/m/Y",strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '27/05/1990')));
```

Comment: Funcionou só usando o `empty`, nem precisei mudar nada na saída. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece é o seguinte:
Se strtotime($var1) retornar `false` então date("d-m-Y",strtotime($var1)); define a data padrão 31/12/1969.

Para resolver isso verifique strtotime($var1).

```
$time = strtotime($var1);
$date = ($time === false) ? '0000-00-00 00:00:00' : date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
echo $date;
```